# How does the GCC implementation of modulo (%) work, and why does it not use the div instruction?

Tags: gcc, assembly, optimization, x86

I was trying to work out how to calculate modulo 10 in assembly so i compiled the following c code in gcc to see what it came up with.

```
unsigned int i=999;
unsigned int j=i%10;
```

To my surprise I got

```
movl    -4(%ebp), %ecx
movl    $-858993459, %edx
movl    %ecx, %eax
mull    %edx
shrl    $3, %edx
movl    %edx, %eax
sall    $2, %eax
addl    %edx, %eax
addl    %eax, %eax
movl    %ecx, %edx
subl    %eax, %edx
movl    %edx, %eax
movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
```

Where -4(%ebp) or "i" is the input and -12(%ebp) or "j" is the answer. I've tested this and it does work no matter what number you make -4(%ebp).

My question is how does this code work and how is it better than using the div operand.

Comment: Are you familiar with 32-bits?

Comment: [Integer division by constants](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdev/archive/2005/12/12/502980.aspx)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.asm.x86/BPkTrwLEgq8/_LbijZ5QD-cJ

Comment: @JensBjörnhager - I would consider the much improved results and extensions from the paper: [Improved division by invariant integers](https://gmplib.org/~tege/division-paper.pdf).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Second question first: `div` is a very slow instruction (more than 20 clock cycles). The sequence above consists of more instructions, but they're all relatively fast, so it's a net win in terms of speed.

The first five instructions (up to and including the `shrl`) compute i/10 (I'll explain how in a minute).

The next few instructions multiply the result by 10 again, but avoiding the `mul`/`imul` instructions (whether this is a win or not depends on the exact processor you're targeting - newer x86s have very fast multipliers, but older ones don't).

```
movl    %edx, %eax   ; eax=i/10
sall    $2, %eax     ; eax=(i/10)*4
addl    %edx, %eax   ; eax=(i/10)*4 + (i/10) = (i/10)*5
addl    %eax, %eax   ; eax=(i/10)*5*2 = (i/10)*10
```

This is then subtracted from `i` again to obtain `i - (i/10)*10` which is `i % 10` (for unsigned numbers).

Finally, on the computation of i/10: The basic idea is to replace division by 10 with multiplication by 1/10. The compiler does a fixed-point approximation of this by multiplying with (2**35 / 10 + 1) - that's the magic value loaded into `edx`, though it's output as a signed value even though it's really unsigned - and right-shifting the result by 35. This turns out to give the right result for all 32-bit integers.

There's algorithms to determine this kind of approximation which guarantee that the error is less than 1 (which for integers means it's the right value) and GCC obviously uses one :)

Final remark: If you want to actually see GCC compute a modulo, make the divisor variable (e.g. a function parameter) so it can't do this kind of optimization. Anyway, on x86, you compute modulo using `div`. `div` expects the 64-bit dividend in `edx:eax` (high 32 bits in edx, low 32 bits in eax - clear edx to zero if you're working with a 32-bit number) and divides that by whatever operand you specify (e.g. `div ebx` divides `edx:eax` by `ebx`). It returns the quotient in `eax` and the remainder in `edx`. `idiv` does the same for signed values.

Answer (score 7):

The first part, up to `shrl $3, %edx`, implements a fast integer division by 10. There are a few  different algorithms that work when the number by which you divide is known in advance. Note that 858993459 is "0.2 * 2^32". The reason to do this is because, even though there is an integer division instruction `div`/`idiv` in the instruction set, it's typically very slow, several times slower than multiplication.

The second part calculates the remainder by multiplying the result of division by 10 (in an indirect way, via shifts and adds; presumably the compiler thinks that it will be faster that way) and then subtracting that from the original number.