# Assembly Language - How to do Modulo?

Tags: assembly, x86, modulo, integer-division

Is there something like a modulo operator or instruction in x86 assembly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361979/calculating-modulo-in-assembly

Comment: For *efficient* modulo by a known constant (or potentially just a loop invariant), see [How does the GCC implementation of modulo (%) work, and why does it not use the div instruction?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4361979) and [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41183935)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If your modulus / divisor is a known constant, and you care about performance, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361979/how-does-the-gcc-implementation-of-modulo-work-and-why-does-it-not-use-the) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi).  A multiplicative inverse is even possible for loop-invariant values that aren't known until runtime, e.g. see https://libdivide.com/  (But without JIT code-gen, that's less efficient than hard-coding just the steps necessary for one constant.)

**Never use `div` for known powers of 2: it's *much* slower than `and`** for remainder, or right-shift for divide.  Look at C compiler output for examples of unsigned or signed division by powers of 2, e.g. [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27unsigned+unsigned_div8(unsigned+x)+%7B+return+x/8%3B+%7D%0Aunsigned+unsigned_rem8(unsigned+x)+%7B+return+x%258%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+signed_div8(int+x)+%7B+return+x/8%3B+%7D%0Aint+signed_rem8(int+x)+%7B+return+x%258%3B+%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g91,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-O3+-m32+-mregparm%3D2%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+9.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang800,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-O3+-m32+-mregparm%3D2%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+8.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).  If you know a runtime input is a power of 2, use `lea eax, [esi-1]` ; `and eax, edi` or something like that to do `x & (y-1)`.  Modulo 256 is even more efficient: `movzx eax, cl` has zero latency on recent Intel CPUs ([mov-elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all)), as long as the two registers are separate.

---

### In the simple/general case: unknown value at runtime

**The [`DIV` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div)** (and its counterpart [`IDIV`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/idiv) for signed numbers) gives both the quotient and remainder.  For unsigned, remainder and modulus are the same thing.  For signed `idiv`, it gives you [the remainder (not modulus)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder) which can be negative:
e.g. `-5 / 2 = -2   rem -1`.  x86 division semantics exactly match C99's `%` operator.

`DIV r32` divides a 64-bit number in `EDX:EAX` by a 32-bit operand (in any register or memory) and stores the quotient in `EAX` and the remainder in `EDX`.  It faults on overflow of the quotient.

**Unsigned 32-bit example** (works in any mode)

```
mov eax, 1234          ; dividend low half
mov edx, 0             ; dividend high half = 0.  prefer  xor edx,edx

mov ebx, 10            ; divisor can be any register or memory

div ebx       ; Divides 1234 by 10.
        ; EDX =   4 = 1234 % 10  remainder
        ; EAX = 123 = 1234 / 10  quotient
```

In 16-bit assembly you can do `div bx` to divide a 32-bit operand in `DX:AX` by `BX`. See Intel's [Architectures Software Developer’s Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) for more information.

**Normally always use `xor edx,edx` before unsigned `div`** to zero-extend EAX into EDX:EAX.  **This is how you do "normal" 32-bit / 32-bit => 32-bit division.**

For signed division, **use `cdq` before `idiv`** to *sign*-extend EAX into EDX:EAX.  See also [Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416593/why-should-edx-be-0-before-using-the-div-instruction).  For other operand-sizes, use `cbw` (AL->AX), `cwd` (AX->DX:AX), `cdq` (EAX->EDX:EAX), or `cqo` (RAX->RDX:RAX) to set the top half to `0` or `-1` according to the sign bit of the low half.

`div` / `idiv` are available in operand-sizes of 8, 16, 32, and (in 64-bit mode) 64-bit.  64-bit operand-size is much slower than 32-bit or smaller on current Intel CPUs, but AMD CPUs only care about the actual magnitude of the numbers, regardless of operand-size.

Note that 8-bit operand-size is special: the implicit inputs/outputs are in AH:AL (aka AX), not DL:AL.  See [8086 assembly on DOSBox: Bug with idiv instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574914/8086-assembly-on-dosbox-bug-with-idiv-instruction/43575674#43575674) for an example.

**Signed 64-bit division example** (requires 64-bit mode)

```
   mov    rax,  0x8000000000000000   ; INT64_MIN = -9223372036854775808
   mov    ecx,  10           ; implicit zero-extension is fine for positive numbers

   cqo                       ; sign-extend into RDX, in this case = -1 = 0xFF...FF
   idiv   rcx
       ; quotient  = RAX = -922337203685477580 = 0xf333333333333334
       ; remainder = RDX = -8                  = 0xfffffffffffffff8
```

---

#### Limitations / common mistakes

**`div dword 10` is not encodeable** into machine code (so your assembler will report an error about invalid operands).

Unlike with `mul`/`imul` (where you should normally use faster 2-operand `imul r32, r/m32` or 3-operand `imul r32, r/m32, imm8/32` instead that don't waste time writing a high-half result), there is no newer opcode for division by an immediate, or 32-bit/32-bit => 32-bit division or remainder without the high-half dividend input.

Division is so slow and (hopefully) rare that they didn't bother to add a way to let you avoid EAX and EDX, or to use an immediate directly.

---

**div and idiv will fault if the quotient doesn't fit into one register** (AL / AX / EAX / RAX, the same width as the dividend).  This includes division by zero, but will also happen with a non-zero EDX and a smaller divisor.  This is why C compilers just zero-extend or sign-extend instead of splitting up a 32-bit value into DX:AX.

And also why `INT_MIN / -1` is C undefined behaviour: it overflows the signed quotient on 2's complement systems like x86.  See [Why does integer division by -1 (negative one) result in FPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378104/why-does-integer-division-by-1-negative-one-result-in-fpe) for an example of x86 vs. ARM.  x86 `idiv` does indeed fault in this case.

The x86 exception is `#DE` - divide exception.  On Unix/Linux systems, the kernel delivers a SIGFPE arithmetic exception signal to processes that cause a #DE exception.  ([On which platforms does integer divide by zero trigger a floating point exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262572/on-which-platforms-does-integer-divide-by-zero-trigger-a-floating-point-exceptio))

For `div`, using a dividend with `high_half < divisor` is safe.  e.g. `0x11:23 / 0x12` is less than `0xff` so it fits in an 8-bit quotient.

Extended-precision division of a huge number by a small number can be implemented by using the remainder from one chunk as the high-half dividend (EDX) for the next chunk.  This is probably why they chose remainder=EDX quotient=EAX instead of the other way around.

Comment: But GCC does not use div because it is slow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361979/how-does-the-gcc-implementation-of-module-work-and-why-does-it-not-use-the

Comment: I expanded this a lot because questions about `div` are pretty common, so this looked like a good place to cover things.  I think the example is still highly visible to give people what they're looking for quickly.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to do floor division and canonical modulus (not remainder) with x86 assembly? For example, `-2 // 5` is `-1` and `-2 %% 5` is `3` (which together satisfy `a %% b == a - ((a // b) * b)`), while with truncated divison and remainder we have `-2 / 5` is `0` and `-2 % 5` is `-2` (which together satisfy `a % b == a - ((a / b) * b)`).

Comment: @AaronFranke: Not off the top of my head, unless absolute values of something just work for the modulus.  Perhaps the usual multiplicative inverse for a constant divisor would actually work better that way. Probably a good idea to ask that as a new question (and link it from here.)

Answer (score 38):

If you compute modulo a power of two, using bitwise AND is simpler and generally faster than performing division. If `b` is a power of two, `a % b == a & (b - 1)`.

For example, let's take a value in register **EAX, modulo 64**.
The simplest way would be `AND EAX, 63`, because 63 is 111111 in binary.

The masked, higher digits are not of interest to us. Try it out!

Analogically, instead of using MUL or DIV with powers of two, bit-shifting is the way to go. Beware signed integers, though!

Comment: What if ```b=0```
 ?

Comment: @LetsGoBrandon Modulo is similar to division in that it is undefined for `b=0`.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to see what a modulus operator looks like on various architectures is to use the Godbolt Compiler Explorer.

https://godbolt.org/z/64zKGr

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care too much about performance and want to use the straightforward way, you can use either `DIV` or `IDIV`.

`DIV` or `IDIV` takes only one operand where it divides
a certain register with this operand, the operand can
be **register** or **memory location** only.

**When operand is a byte:**
AL = AL / operand, AH = remainder (modulus).

Ex:

`MOV AL,31h  ; Al = 31h`

`DIV BL  ; Al (quotient)= 08h, Ah(remainder)= 01h`

**when operand is a word:**
AX = (AX) / operand, DX = remainder (modulus).

Ex:

`MOV AX,9031h  ; Ax = 9031h`

`DIV BX  ; Ax=1808h & Dx(remainder)= 01h`