# intel x86 assembly - collecting remainders of a division

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, division, masm

How can I collect the remainders of a `div` instruction into a register so that it can be converted into a string and displayed to the console. For example:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
.data
  adrs1 dd 0
  adrs2 dd 0
.code
start:
  mov eax, 6        ; add 6 to eax
  mov ebx, 7        ; add 7 to ebx
  imul eax, ebx     ; multiply both numbers, result is in eax
  mov ecx, 10       ; add 10 to ecx
  idiv eax:ecx, edx ; divide eax (result of mul) by 10 so that I can separate the              digits into single characters so  I can display them.
                    ; Numbers will be 4 and 2. Is the result of the division stored in EDX?
  mov adrs1, eax      ; mov the '4' from the '42' result of the multiplication into 'adrs'
  mov adrs2, edx      ; mov the remainder of the division to adrs2
  add adrs1, 50       ; make the result the correct ASCII character for the result
  add adrs2, 50       ; " "
  invoke StdOut, addr adrs1 ; display adrs1
  invoke StdOut, addr adrs2 ; display adrs2
  invoke ExitProcess, 0 ; exit
end start
```

I need to display the remainders of the division. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Progrmr

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement the mod operator in assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231882/how-to-implement-the-mod-operator-in-assembly)

Comment: Thanks, but is that code implementable in MASM?

Comment: Doing an IDIV leaves quotient and remainders in registers... so you don't have to "do" anything to get the remainder into a register.  What's the source of your question?

Comment: I'm trying to separate a number (e.g. 1405) into separate digits (that's why I want the remainder, because I'm dividing by 10 to separate the digits past the decimal point) so that I can print them to the console.

Comment: @Progrmr The remainder of a `div` instruction goes into `edx`. BTW why don't you use the [BCD features of the x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_BCD_opcode)?