# Division + Modulo in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to get the remainder and quotient of a number divided by 10.

I have this code block right here, is this correct?
I can't seem to have an output from the variables when I try to print them

```
mov al, [dividend]
mov ah, 0
mov byte[dividend], 10
mov byte[quotient], al
mov byte[remainder], ah
```

Given that I have these variables:

```
dividend resb 1
quotient resb 1
remainder resb 1
```

---

I'm using Ubuntu 13 x86. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any arithmetic operation being performed there...

Comment: Im new to assembly, im not sure what im doing. what should I add to perform the div operation?

Comment: @BurnzZ a `div` operation. Or maybe `idiv`. Should it be signed or unsigned?

Comment: it would be unsigned. on which line should I insert the div operation?

Comment: Depends on what you want to divide. I suggest you first explain in your question **exactly** what you want to do: the more details the better, and examples are welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assembly Language - How to Do Modulo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021772/assembly-language-how-to-do-modulo)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the `div` instruction, like so:

```
mov al,[dividend]
mov ah,0
mov cl,10            ; divisor is stored here
div cl               ; division is performed here
mov [quotient],al
mov [remainder],ah
```