# Understanding division in FASM assembler: What happens when huge number is divided by tiny number?

Tags: assembly, fasm

I'm trying to understand how the division instruction in FASM works.

If I get it right then it expects the value to divide in the register (e)dx and (e)ax. See accepted answer here: [Assembly Language - How to Do Modulo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021772/assembly-language-how-to-do-modulo)

After the operation the result is stored in (e)ax. The remainder is stored in (e)dx.

**But what happens if I divide a very large number with a very tiny divisor?**

Let's say I would store 2 exp. 64 in edx:eax. Then divide it by a number <= 1 .
Then the result would be something >= 2 exp. 64 ...

**How could that work?**

The result wouldn't fit into eax alone.

Can someone help me to understand the issue?

Comment: 2^64 doesn't fit in the 64-bit edx:eax register pair.  And unless you're talking about negative numbers, the only unsigned integers <= 1 are 1 and 0.  Division by zero always raises #DE, and so does any division where the quotient doesn't fit in the destination register, as explained in the [insn ref manual](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html).  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262572/on-which-platforms-does-integer-divide-by-zero-trigger-a-floating-point-exceptio for more about #DE and what OSes do in response.  (e.g. POSIX OSes deliver SIGFPE.)

Comment: Thanks. Helped me already to understand it better ...