# Strange behavior in VB6 when calculating a negative number Mod a number which is a power of 2

Tags: vb6

I was debugging an old piece of code developed in VB6 and found something very strange. It can be demonstrated with the following simple code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    a = 0
    Text1.Text = a - 1
    Text2.Text = CStr((a - 1) Mod 4)

    b = 0
    b = b - 1
    Text3.Text = b
    Text4.Text = CStr(b Mod 4)

    c = 0 - 1
    Text5.Text = c
    Text6.Text = CStr(c Mod 4)

End Sub
```

Here's what the form looked like:

[image]

You would think after the button is clicked Text2, Text4 and Text6 should show the same content, which is -1. That is the case when I pressed F5 to run it in the IDE.

This is what it looked like when I ran it in IDE:

[image]

The strange thing happened when I made an exe from IDE and ran the exe itself. Text1 and Text6 showed -1 but Text4 showed 3.

This is what it looked like when I ran the exe outside of IDE:

[image]

This happens only if the second operand is a power of 2. When I changed the 4's to 5, all the text boxes showed -1.

I tested this on 2 Windows 10 machines and got the same result.

I know VB6 is old and not many people still have it available now for test. I appreciate it if someone can help me understand this.

Thanks.

Comment: I see the same behavior here, strange indeed.

Comment: Seems like a optimization bug. `Text4.Text = CStr(b Mod 4&)` fixes the issue. Or you can use `Long`s.

Comment: Looks indeed like optimization issue. 2 additional possibilities are to 1) is to the the compile option to _Compile to P code_*) instead of _Compile to system code (Native code)_. Or set _Compile to system code (Native code)_ and pick the option _No optimization_.
*) I always compiled to P code. Except for number crunching, compiling to native code doesn't do noticeable enhancements. And for number crunching, VB is perhaps not the best tool in town. I remember another weirdness that caused me to settle on P code for everything.

Comment: FWIW, I just popped open Calc,exe in Scientific mode, input -1 Mod 4 and the answer was 3.

Comment: Thanks. Disabling optimization did solve the problem.

Comment: @tcarvin Indeed, 3 on Windows 10, however -1 on Windows 7.

Comment: @GSerg that is unexpected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a compiler bug. The compiler fails to recognize that the value is signed in case of an `Integer` (16-bit value), but [does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58663568/strange-behavior-in-vb6-when-calculating-a-negative-number-mod-a-number-which-is#comment103641982_58663568) respect it in case of a `Long`.

The code that performs modulo 4 is almost the same in each case and follows the [optimized pattern for modulo powers of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27589182/11683):

Long (`b Mod 4&`):

```asm
or   eax, 0xFFFFFFFF  # eax = 0xFFFFFFFF (which is -1)
and  eax, 0x80000003  # eax = 0x80000003 The modulo op, note it's signed because of the 8

jns  other_code       # Skip the next three lines if the result is non-negative (it isn't here)

dec  eax              # eax = 0x80000002
or   eax, 0xFFFFFFFC  # eax = 0xFFFFFFFE
inc  eax              # eax = 0xFFFFFFFF (which is -1)

other_code:
```

In the end `eax` contains 0xFFFFFFFF, which is -1, which is passed for display.

---

Integer (`b Mod 4`):

```asm
or   eax, 0xFFFFFFFF  # eax = 0xFFFFFFFF, ax = 0xFFFF (which is -1 in both cases)
and  ax,  0x3         # eax = 0xFFFF0003, ax = 0x0003. Should have been "and ax, 0x8003!"

jns  other_code       # Skip the next three lines if the result is non-negative (it incorrectly is)

dec  ax               # Skipped
or   ax,  0xFFFC      # Skipped
inc  ax               # Skipped

other_code:
```

In the end `eax` contains 0xFFFF0003 and is then passed to the `__vbaStrI2` function that will apparently ignore the two high bytes and only use the `0003`.

If `and ax, 0x8003` was used instead of the `and ax, 0x3`, then the skipped lines would trigger and convert the `0xFFFF0003` into `0xFFFFFFFF`, which is -1.

---

With optimizations disabled, the bitwise modulo math is replaced with a straightforward division:

```asm
sub   ax, 0x1          # b = b - 1
mov   cx, 0x4          # Prepare division by 4
idiv  cx               # Integer division
```

---

As for why the cases for `a` and `c` work as expected, this is because the compiler calculates `-1 Mod 4` at the compilation stage and hardcodes the result in the executable:

```asm
push  0xFFFFFFFF       # Pass hardcoded -1 for display

other_code:
```

Technically there is nothing that would prevent it from doing the same in the case of `b`, because it can also prove the value being divided is `-1`. I cannot tell for sure why it did not do this - maybe it stopped the static analysis one step too soon, or maybe the resulting code for also writing the `-1` back to the memory address of `b` would be less efficient in its opinion.

Comment: This explains the different results between Integer and Long. In my original example, all 3 variables are integers, not Long.

Comment: @elin For `a` and `c`, the compiler does not have to store the result of `a - 1` and `c - 1` back into `a` and `c`, and it can prove the value before subtraction is 0, so it does not emit code for calculating `Mod` at all and directly pushes `-1` onto the stack as a constant (`push 0xffffffff`).