# How to use the div instruction to find remainder in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, division

```
mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov edx, 0
mov ax, 31
mul cx
mov bx, 12
div bx
add bp, ax
mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov bp, bp
mov al, 7
div al
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong with the div al instruction in this block of code, so as I'm debugging every number of bp i calculated, when i divide by al it give me 1 as the remainder, why is this happen?

the remainder should be store back to ah register

thank in advance

edited code :

```
mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov edx, 0
mov ax, 31
mul cx
mov bx, 12
div bx
add bp, ax
mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov ax, bp
mov bl, 7
div bl
mov al, 0
```

Comment: `mov reg, 0` would be better written as `xor reg, reg`

Comment: How to without requiring `div`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021772/assembly-language-how-to-do-modulo GCC 4.8 does not use div by default because it is slow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361979/how-does-the-gcc-implementation-of-module-work-and-why-does-it-not-use-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited code:

```
mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov ax, 31
mul cx
mov bx, 12
div bx
add bp, ax
mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov edx, 0
mov ax, bp
mov bx, 7
div bx
mov esi, edx 
mov eax, 0
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `al` as divisor, because the command `div` assumes `ax` to be the dividend.

This is an example for dividing `bp` by `7`

```
mov ax,bp // ax is the dividend
mov bl,7  // prepare divisor
div bl    // divide ax by bl
```

This is 8 bit division, so yes the remainder will be stored in `ah`. The result is in `al`.

To clarify: If you write to `al` you partially overwrite `ax`!

```
|31..16|15-8|7-0|
        |AH.|AL.|
        |AX.....|
|EAX............|
```

Comment: @bluebk where do you get integer overflow? you should not write anything to al if you want to divide bp by something, because you will overwrite ax (the dividend)

Comment: i got integer over flow at div bl instruction in the edited code

Comment: @bluebk well then maybe this is because your result does not fit into `al`. If `bp` is anything greater than 0x700 you will get the integer overflow

Comment: my bp for example is 9E8, then should i use bx instead of bl?

Comment: @bluebk you can't do a 8 bit division of 9b8 by 7. the result is greater than 0xff.