# What's cheaper, Modulus 2 or direct if comparison?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got 2 Page instances, random number of pages to show.

Flipping pages replaces the currentPage with the other page (which becomes the current page)

To set current page, would it be cheaper to simply do something like this:

```
currentPage = (currentPage == page1) ? page2 : page1;
```

or cheaper to do something like this:

```
currentPage = this["page"+pageNum % 2 + 1]
```

My instinct says a ternary or if would be the cheaper option, but I'm interested in seeing if anyone knows for certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure the first option is cheaper, a modulus is more assembly operations than doing a simple if statement check.

See this for assembly instructions about modulus: [How does the GCC implementation of module (%) work, and why does it not use the div instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361979/calculating-modulo-in-assembly)

Comment: Thanks. I thought that might be the case, great to get some reasoning behind it though.