# How to write modulus (% in C++) in assembly language

Tags: c++, assembly

I do not know what instruction I have to use in order to translate %2

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
     int number;
     cin >> number;
     if (number % 2 == 0) {    // I cannot translate this part.
       cout << "Even\n";
    }
    else {
       cout << "Odd\n";
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: compile your program and get assembler output from compiler. Job done.

Comment: Let the compiler help you :) Translate to assembly using your favorite C++ compiler, and check the output.

Comment: Let the compiler do that.

Comment: Your question is puzzling: do you wish to convert your program in C++ to assembly, _or_ do you want to know what's the equivalent code in assembly for the remainder operation?

Comment: And hey, an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021772/assembly-language-how-to-do-modulo)! And [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361979/calculating-modulo-in-assembly)!

Comment: What is your target platform?  Different processors use different assembly language to perform the operation.  This is twice you haven't specified.

Comment: Most C compilers have an option to generate assembly listing while compiling. On MSVC, it's /FA.

Comment: Modulo is nothing. If I were you I wound rather panic about hand-translating std::cout::operator<<.

Comment: @AlexWatson: That's just a function call.

Comment: @Keith Which you need to synthesize yourself, cout being a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulo is typically produced by the division instruction. However, taking modulo 2, 4, 8, 16, and so on is a special case: because the numbers are stored in the binary form, these checks can be done with an `AND` instruction.

The fastest way of checking divisibility by 2 is looking at the least significant bit of a value. Use `AND` instruction with the value of `1`, i.e. `number & 1`. Its result is always the same as `number % 2`. Most modern compilers (and some archaic ones) will do this as an easy optimization.

For other powers of two, `AND` with that value minus one, i.e. for `x % 4` use `x & 3`, for `x % 8` use `x & 7`, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

In a typical assembly language, the integer divide instruction will also give you the remainder. In the case of remainder when dividing by 2, it's a lot easier to translate to a bit-wise `AND` with bit 0 though. E.g., on x86:

```
    mov eax, number

    ; test sets the flags based on a bitwise and, but discards the result
    test eax, 1

    mov esi, offset even_string
    jz print_it
    mov esi, offset odd_string
print_it:
    ; print string whose base address is in esi
```

If you need to check for divisibility by some arbitrary number (instead of just 2), the division instruction will usually produce both the quotient and the remainder. Again, using x86 as a demonstration:

```
idiv ebx  ; divisor in edx:eax
; quotient in eax, remainder in edx
```

Answer (score 0):

In assembly languages that don't have a bit test instruction, you will have to (Boolean) AND the value with 1:

```
    LODI, R0  #5    ; Load register 0 with the number 5.
    ANDI, R0  #1    ; Boolean AND the register with one (1).
    JUMZ      Value_is_even; jump if the value is zero.
;
;   Go here if the value is odd.
```