# How can I get the quotient and the remainder in a single step?

Tags: c++, c, modulo, integer-division

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Divide and Get Remainder at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895081/divide-and-get-remainder-at-the-same-time)

Is it possible to get both the quotient and the remainder of integer division in a single step, i.e., without performing integer division twice?

Comment: You mean the "result" of the division? It's called the "quotient".

Comment: well, lets say I call " 25 % 10" which results in 5, cuz 2x10 = 20 and 5 is the remainder, what I want to get is the 2 out of the modulo operation as well, is it possible?

Comment: Some CPUs and some languages have this capability, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895081/divide-and-get-remainder-at-the-same-time

Comment: Most compilers (should) optimise something like `int c = a % b; int d = a / b;` into one operation (eg, `div` on x86, which returns both).

Comment: @ddriver, yep, that's the quotient.

Comment: What do you mean by single step? Are you looking a for single function to call?  Are you looking for something that generates a single assembly instruction?  Are you looking for something that generates assembly that takes a certain number of clock cycles to execute?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`div` will do this.  See [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div) and example:

```
/* div example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  div_t divresult;
  divresult = div (38,5);
  printf ("38 div 5 => %d, remainder %d.\n", divresult.quot, divresult.rem);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
38 div 5 => 7, remainder 3.
```

EDIT:

The C Specification says:

### 7.20 General utilities

```
The types declared are size_t and wchar_t (both described in 7.17),
div_t
which is a structure type that is the type of the value returned by the div function,
ldiv_t
which is a structure type that is the type of the value returned by the ldiv function, and
lldiv_t
which is a structure type that is the type of the value returned by the lldiv function.
```

... but it doesn't say what the definition of `div_t` is.

Comment: @ddriver:  Yes, but see my edit.

Comment: yes, thank you very much for the detailed response

Comment: FYI - The [GLIBC implementation of `div`](http://bit.ly/uqny7z) simply does a divide and a modulo, so you aren't gaining anything. Actually, what you gain is the function call overhead.

Comment: @MikeSteinert: That depends on your architecture - eg glibc has an [assembly implementation of `div` for Alpha](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/alpha/div.S;h=d1a724d3758997ed800f995fba5ddf2ae82e148e;hb=febcd83655138bcb01b2680e170e6773a1ec813c)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a standard function called [`div()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/div) (and `ldiv`, and maybe even `lldiv`) that does this.