# How can I calculate divide and modulo for integers in C#?

Tags: c#, math, operators, division, modulo

How can I calculate division and modulo for integer numbers in C#?

Comment: This might be too basic, but it is a real question...

Comment: A related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10065080/465053) and a must read [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/12/05/whats-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus/) on why `%` operator is **not** the modulus operator in C#.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Here's an answer from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2. To determine the remainder of 7 / 3, use the remainder operator ([%](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator)).

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;

int div = a / b; //quotient is 1
int mod = a % b; //remainder is 2
```

Comment: % returns the remainder, not the modulus (as you point out). They arent the same thing, and can cause problems when dealing with unusual cases (e.g. negative indexes). However, it can be used like the modulus operator when just looking for, e.g., every 10th iteration of a weakly positive indexer. Perhaps you could explain how to calculate the real modulus?

Comment: True, I read posts like this, and I had problems in my application :)

Comment: ...What exactly is the point of declaring `a` and `b` if you aren't going to use them? :D

Comment: @aboveyou00: fixed that for you!

Comment: @Cor_Blimey: The simplest, safest, and most readable way to calculate the modulus is probably to calculate the remainder and--if it's negative, add the base. If the code is ported to a platform which includes a real modulus operator, the adjust-if-negative code may be redundant, but harmless. If one needs both the quotient and real modulus, the safe approach would be to use `/` for the division, multiply and subtract to yield the remainder of whatever form, and if it's necessary to adjust the remainder, adjust the quotient as well. That will work regardless of what the language does for "/".

Comment: @supercat thanks for the response. I wasn't sure if there was a bit of syntactic sugar for it instead. And I agree, if in doubt then calculate it 'properly' from first principles to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: @supercat how can the remainder ever be negative?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: -1 mod 16 is 15, but -1 divided by 15 is zero remainder -1.

Comment: Perhaps the user was searching (like me) for a DivRem function, so the question could be not as trivial as it seems at first glance. Thanks @danodonovan

Comment: The answer is not as simple as this answer claims, as others have also pointed out, and can lead to hard-to-debug mistakes. 
See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065080/mod-explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065080/mod-explanation)

Answer (score 105):

There is also [`Math.DivRem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yda5c8dx.aspx)

```
quotient = Math.DivRem(dividend, divisor, out remainder);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer in my opinion, because it provides the quotient AND the remainder in one function. I am not sure which approach performs better (using "a / b" to get quotient and then "a % b" to get the remainder or Math.DivRem), but this approach certainly is much nicer to read (in my case I need to know both quotient and remainder) - thank you!

Comment: @Igor thanks, when the original question was answered this function didn't exist! However, the function's existence does make as-cii's remark about checking the documentation look a bit silly.... :)

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, `Math.DivRem` does not compute div and mod in one operation. It is just a helper function and its source code is exactly: `public static int DivRem(int a, int b, out int result) { result = a%b; return a/b; }`.

Comment: @NightElfik The implementation could change in the future, and it is  easier for the runtime to identify a method call for optimization than disjoint `div` and `rem` instructions

Comment: @kbolino That's a great prediction, since [it *has* changed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41805430/1030702), at least in .NET Core, to divide & subtract. And there's further optimisations planned in RyuJIT to use a single x86 div instruction, though admittedly the JIT changes should also detect the `%` and `/` operators if used individually.

Answer (score 17):

Fun fact!

The 'modulus' operation is defined as:

```
a % n ==> a - (a/n) * n
```

Ref:[Modular Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

So you *could* roll your own, although it will be FAR slower than the built in % operator:

```
public static int Mod(int a, int n)
{
    return a - (int)((double)a / n) * n;
}
```

Edit: wow, misspoke rather badly here originally, thanks @joren for catching me

Now here I'm relying on the fact that division + cast-to-int in C# is equivalent to `Math.Floor` (i.e., it drops the fraction), but a "true" implementation would instead be something like:

```
public static int Mod(int a, int n)
{
    return a - (int)Math.Floor((double)a / n) * n;
}
```

In fact, you can see the differences between % and "true modulus" with the following:

```
var modTest =
    from a in Enumerable.Range(-3, 6)
    from b in Enumerable.Range(-3, 6)
    where b != 0
    let op = (a % b)
    let mod = Mod(a,b)
    let areSame = op == mod
    select new 
    { 
        A = a,
        B = b,
        Operator = op, 
        Mod = mod, 
        Same = areSame
    };
Console.WriteLine("A      B     A%B   Mod(A,B)   Equal?");
Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
foreach (var result in modTest)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0,-3} | {1,-3} | {2,-5} | {3,-10} | {4,-6}", 
        result.A,
        result.B,
        result.Operator, 
        result.Mod, 
        result.Same);
}
```

Results:

```
A      B     A%B   Mod(A,B)   Equal?
-----------------------------------
-3  | -3  | 0     | 0          | True  
-3  | -2  | -1    | -1         | True  
-3  | -1  | 0     | 0          | True  
-3  | 1   | 0     | 0          | True  
-3  | 2   | -1    | 1          | False 
-2  | -3  | -2    | -2         | True  
-2  | -2  | 0     | 0          | True  
-2  | -1  | 0     | 0          | True  
-2  | 1   | 0     | 0          | True  
-2  | 2   | 0     | 0          | True  
-1  | -3  | -1    | -1         | True  
-1  | -2  | -1    | -1         | True  
-1  | -1  | 0     | 0          | True  
-1  | 1   | 0     | 0          | True  
-1  | 2   | -1    | 1          | False 
0   | -3  | 0     | 0          | True  
0   | -2  | 0     | 0          | True  
0   | -1  | 0     | 0          | True  
0   | 1   | 0     | 0          | True  
0   | 2   | 0     | 0          | True  
1   | -3  | 1     | -2         | False 
1   | -2  | 1     | -1         | False 
1   | -1  | 0     | 0          | True  
1   | 1   | 0     | 0          | True  
1   | 2   | 1     | 1          | True  
2   | -3  | 2     | -1         | False 
2   | -2  | 0     | 0          | True  
2   | -1  | 0     | 0          | True  
2   | 1   | 0     | 0          | True  
2   | 2   | 0     | 0          | True
```

Comment: "Now here I'm relying on the fact that integer division in C# is equivalent to Math.Floor (i.e., it drops the fraction)" - But it's not. Integer divison rounds towards zero, Math.Floor rounds towards negative infinity.

Comment: @Joren Sorry, but no - try running this: `Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => (double)x / 10.0).Select(x => (int)x).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));` - all 0's

Comment: First, I'm talking about *integer division*. What happens if you do a floating-point division and then cast to integer is irrelevant (even though it gives the same result). Second, I'm not sure why you would expect integers between 0 and 9 to give anything other than 0 after dividing by 10 and truncating to the integer part. If that resulted in 1 that would be rounding *away* from zero or towards *positive* infinity. Third, there is *no difference whatsoever* between rounding towards zero and rounding towards negative infinity for positive numbers, so you're not even addressing the issue.

Comment: `Math.Floor(-10.0 / 3.0)` and `-10 / 3` are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @joren ah, I see the disconnect here - no, I'm not performing *integer* division, I'm performing double division, then casting the result to integer - very different.

Comment: @joren but you are correct that there is a huge typo in my example. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Joren There - sorry about that, you were absolutely correct in catching that; don't know what the heck I was thinking when I wrote up the post...

Answer (score 15):

**Division is performed using the `/` operator:**

```
result = a / b;
```

**Modulo division is done using the `%` operator:**

```
result = a % b;
```

Comment: +1: Conveniently leaving out the type makes it a better answer :-) I believe this works with System.Numeric.BigInteger in 4.0 too.

Comment: % --> as Cor_Blimey said, it returns remainder not the modulus. For example: (-5 % 3) == -2 [C#], -5 mod 3 = 1 [wolframalpha.com].

Comment: Note: Modulo is not the same as Modulus. Modulo is the remainder, Modulus is the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

Remainder: a % b
example: 5 % 3 = 2

Divide:

case both variables are integer: 5/3 = 1

case decimal and neeeded integer: Math.Floor(5/3)

or 5/3 - (5%3)/3 if you dont want to use the Math Class

Answer (score -5):

Read two integers from the user. Then compute/display the remainder and quotient,

```
// When the larger integer is divided by the smaller integer
Console.WriteLine("Enter integer 1 please :");
double a5 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter integer 2 please :");
double b5 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double div = a5 / b5;
Console.WriteLine(div);

double mod = a5 % b5;
Console.WriteLine(mod);

Console.ReadLine();
```