# % (mod) explanation

Tags: c#, math, operators, modulo

Today I was writing a program in C#, and I used **%** to calculate some index... My program didn't work, so I debugged it and I realized that "**%**" is not working like in other program languages that I know.

For example:

In Python `%` returns values like this:

```
for x in xrange (-5, 6):
     print x, "% 5 =", x % 5

-5 % 5 = 0
-4 % 5 = 1
-3 % 5 = 2
-2 % 5 = 3
-1 % 5 = 4
0 % 5 = 0
1 % 5 = 1
2 % 5 = 2
3 % 5 = 3
4 % 5 = 4
5 % 5 = 0
```

In C#:

```
for (int i = -5; i < 6; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " % 5 = " + i % 5);
}

-5 % 5 = 0
-4 % 5 = -4
-3 % 5 = -3
-2 % 5 = -2
-1 % 5 = -1
0 % 5 = 0
1 % 5 = 1
2 % 5 = 2
3 % 5 = 3
4 % 5 = 4
5 % 5 = 0
```

Did I do something wrong or is `%` not working like it should?

Comment: In C-derived languages, % is not the modulus operator. It is the *remainder* operator. [Eric Lippert explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen that looks like an answer, not a comment. I can upvote it if you want, though.

Comment: How can I use modulus operator in C#?

Comment: Wolfy - just add 5 if the value is negative.

Comment: @Wolfy `c = a % b; if (c < 0)  { c += b; } return c;`

Comment: Painfully, Microsoft has blasted Lippert's blog post @RaymondChen mentions. Thankfully archive.org has many copies. [This is one](https://web.archive.org/web/20120211021512/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx). **EDIT:** Actually it looks like they moved it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/whats-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus) with no forward. /shrug

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the different behaviour is by design. The different languages just ascribe different meanings to the `%` operator.

You ask:

> How can I use modulus operator in C#?

You can define a modulus operator yourself that behaves the same way as the Python `%` operator:

```
int mod(int a, int n)
{
    int result = a % n;
    if ((result<0 && n>0) || (result>0 && n<0)) {
        result += n;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your code gives incorrect results, for example mod(-5, 5) == 5. For a working example, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain)

Comment: @Drake @DavidHeffernan I fixed the bug in this answer's code. The problem was that it should check for the `result`'s value, not for `a`'s value.

Answer (score 10):

Both answers are correct. Although personally I think the "always positive" one makes more sense.

You can define your own modulus function that only gives positive answers like this:

```
int mod(int a, int n) {
    return ((a%n)+n) % n;
}
```

Comment: what does `mod(-5, 2)` return?

Comment: Damn... Okay, let me try again.

Comment: `mod(-2, -5)` returns -2. You said that it should return always positive values, but there are inputs which cause it to return negative values. Is this acceptable? Is it expected?

Comment: I have found that it's more efficient to write it like this: `int c = a % b; if (c < 0) { c += b; } return c;` although note that it doesn't account for negative divisors

Comment: @EricLippert In theory it should return between 0 and the second argument (so if the divisor is negative then it should be negative, and positive when divisor is positive, regardless of dividend's sign) but negative divisors are very uncommon.

Comment: To account for negative divisors, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10065670/4441547 This is probably fairly uncommon though so for most use cases the above answer works fine.

Answer (score 7):

In [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), one defines *classes* of numbers based on the modulo. In other words, in modulo *m* arithmetic, a number *n* is equivalent (read: the same) to *n* + *m*, *n* - *m*, *n* + *2m*, *n* - *2m*, etc.

One defines *m* "baskets" and every number falls in one (and only one) of them.

> **Example**: one can say "It's 4:30 pm" or one can say "It's 16:30". Both forms mean exactly the same time, but are different *representations* of it.

Thus both, the Python and C# results are correct! The numbers are *the same* in the modulo *5* arithmetic you chose. It would also have been *mathematically* correct to return (5, 6, 7, 8, 9) for example. Just a bit odd.

As for the choice of representation (in other words, the choice on how to represent negative numbers), that is just a case of different design choices between the two languages.

> However, that is not at all what the % operator actually does in C#. The % operator is not the canonical modulus operator; it is the remainder operator. The A % B operator actually answer the question "If I divided A by B using integer arithmetic, what would the remainder be?"

— [*What's the difference? Remainder vs Modulus* by Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/12/05/whats-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus/)

---

Quick snippet to get the canonical modulus:

```
return ((n % m) + m) % m;
```

---

Test implementation:

**Mono/C#**:

```
machine:~ user$ cat mod.cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Mod(-2, 5));
        Console.WriteLine(Mod(-5, 5));
        Console.WriteLine(Mod(-2, -5));
    }

    public static int Mod (int n, int m)
    {
        return ((n % m) + m) % m;
    }
}

machine:~ user$ mono mod.exe
3
0
-2
```

**Python**:

```
machine:~ user$ cat mod.py
print -2%5;
print -5%5;
print -2%-5;

machine:~ user$ python mod.py
3
0
-2
```

Comment: What is the "canonical modulus" of -2 and -5?  Your program gives -2, but I think you were intending it to give non-negative results. Care to try again?

Comment: @EricLippert It does not. It returns 3 and 0, respectively. See my edit.

Comment: I assure you, your snippet says that the canonical modulus of -2 and -5 is -2. Try it: `class P { static void Main() { int n = -2, m = -5; System.Console.WriteLine(((n%m)+m)%m)); } }` Run that, you'll get -2 printed out. If it was your intention that the canonical modulus be non-negative, you have failed to achieve your intention. Care to try again?

Comment: @Eric Ah, gotcha! -5 was the modulo and not another input... OK, that's still consistent with python, though: `python -c 'print -2%-5;'` returns `-2`. That's what the OP was expecting, I think.

Comment: For a version that handles negative divisors correctly, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10065670/4441547 This is probably fairly uncommon though so for most use cases the above answer works fine.