# x++ operator for playing gif animations: How do it work together in this example?

Tags: c#, gif

I'm making small games in C# for fun, and used a guide on youtube to help me in the process. However, I use some of the code the youtuber shows, but there's a bit of it, I don't understand completely.

```
index++;

//gif animations
if (right == true && index % 15 == 0)
{
    player.Image = Image.FromFile("char_right.gif");
}
if (left == true && index % 15 == 0)
{
    player.Image = Image.FromFile("char_left.gif");
}
```

I know that I can change the "% 15" values, and choose how much of my .gif file should be played, during the game, but I'm not sure how the operater "index++" make it work. "index" is defined:

```
int index = 0;
```

Can anyone please explain it to me, as I don't want to use something, I don't completely understand :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part specifically don't you understand? The [Increment Operator (++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx) increments `index` by one...

Comment: it's mostly how index++ works in the line:
if (right == true && index % 15 == 0)
Not sure what "index % 15 == 0" do, which is so important for the animation

Comment: In addition to CodeCaster link, see the [modulus operator "%"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065080/mod-explanation) which returns the rest of an integer division

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Mmh, there's really a `x++` tag. People should really start to read the tag descriptions when asking a question-