# How to get remainder and mod by dividing using C#

Tags: c#

I want to divide 5 by 3 using C#. What operator can I use to get the remainder or modulus after dividing?

Comment: Did you try something for this ? to start of check `/` and `%` and their usage, good if you can come up with a specific issue with the code attempting this.

Comment: `int remainder, quotient = Math.DivRem(5, 3, out remainder);`

Comment: This page comes up third in search results for 'c# remainder' after MSDN and has been viewed 23988 times so this is a very useful question to many. Additionally the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383050/how-can-i-calculate-divide-and-modulo-for-integers asks a very similar question with similar answers and has not been closed.In fact it has been highly upvoted. Either both should be closed or both opened. I don't have enough points to vote to re-open this, but if I did I would.

Comment: It's always amusing when I google something and one of the first results is a page where people are telling someone to google it.  Thanks to those who gave an answer.

Comment: Agreed, this is very much a Q & A question, I don't see why it was closed for the stated reason. Voting to reopen.

Comment: In .NET 6+: `var (quotient, remainder) = Math.DivRem(5, 3)` otherwise `var quotient = Math.DivRem(5, 3, out var remainder)`

Answer (score 66):

You can do this:

```
 double answer = 5.0/3.0;

 int remainder = 5 % 3;

 int quotient = 5 / 3;
```

Comment: Also `double ieee = Math.IEEERemainder(5.0, 3.0);`.

Comment: Int remainder is not in liberary. it does not accept ..