# Why isn't there Math.Pow that takes an int as the exponent?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, math

I read that the `Math.Pow` implementation is pretty complicated to be able to handle fractional powers. Why isn't there a version that takes an int for the exponent to make a faster version when you don't need fractional powers?

Comment: Check out this link on SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383587/how-do-you-do-integer-exponentiation-in-c

Comment: Thanks but would it be fast as a MS' version? Because they use an external call for their Pow method.

Comment: external calls are not directly a guarantee for speed.

Comment: Thanks Henk, I assumed they wanted to write it in C++ to make it faster. What other reasons would there be to do that for this case?

Comment: I was talking to a graphics programmer here and he said the implementation to handle fractional powers is much more complicated than just multiplying values, so I assumed I get hit by the same performance penalty even when my exponent is not fractional.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398442/why-isnt-int-powint-base-int-exponent-in-the-standard-c-libraries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you'd just need to convert it back into a float to multiply it against the logarithm of the base.

## n<sup>m</sup> = e<sup>m × ln n</sup>

Comment: @BlueRaja OP Clearly states only int for exponent.

Comment: Unless you implement the integer exponentiation using integer arithmetic... which will probably be faster than running those exp and ln's.

Answer (score 1):

A decade late but I wanted to give my answer for anyone who runs across this.

I've done lots of assembly work in the past and there is usually an assembly CPU instruction (to interact with the hardware) for `Pow(Double,Double)` but not `Pow(Double,Int)`. Most languages just expose this with a `Pow(Double,Double)` type function. There is no `Pow(Double,Int)` to expose to the user.

So then one can ask, why did Intel not include some hardware(aka many thousand additional transistors). I'm using Intel since they mostly were the ones who set the standard 20 years ago. Intel had limited chip realestate (transistors), and the demand for a performance mixed(mixing double/integer) instruction like that just was needed. In fact, there were not a lot of mixed instructions in general. Double tended to work with double. Float with float. Integer with Integer. There were not really many with mixed types except for instructions to convert back and forth.

Finally, I would say `Pow(Double,Double)` can handle `Pow(Double,Int)` when the *Int* is cast to a double is *good enough*. Chip makers did not use valuable chip realestate for a mixed type instruction.

Answer (score 0):

For a compiler it is only worthwhile to optimize by converting to a series of multiplies, if the exponent is constant. In which case you can write `x*x` or `x*x*x` yourself.

Edit: So if you want to avoid your math is done by the Math.Pow implementation (which uses exponent functions), just don't call it. If Math.Pow would be added for integers, the compiler would have figure out from how it is called if it should emit code for multiplication (if n is constant and small) or the default using exponent functions. That is non-trivial work for a compiler, and there would be no gain in terms of performance.

Comment: So you think it would optimize if I do Math.Pow (3, 5)? The call is external so I can't see the code.

Comment: This utterly misses the point. `Math.Pow` doesn't do a series of multiplications. And even if it did, the library code behind it would use intermediate values even if the exponent was not known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that fast math functions was their first priority when they programmed them (see [Why is Math.DivRem so inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447282/why-is-math-divrem-so-inefficient)).
They could use a expotentiation by square that would be faster, at least for small exponents.

However because floating point is subject to rounding providing 2 different inplementations could mean different results, e.g. for pow(5.9,7) than for pow(5.9,7.0), which may be undesirable in some cases.

Comment: What level of accuracy is guaranteed for the "pow" function?  Guaranteeing precision within 0.5625ulp when raising to an integer power is a little tricky, but guaranteeing it when using exp(ln(base)\*pow) is even harder.  Too C sufficiently botched extended-precision support that such types aren't generally available, since they'd make it much easier to yield a result accurate to `double` precision.

Answer (score -4):

Well, you could write your own (in C):

```
int intPow(int a,int b){
  int answer = a;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<b-1;i++)
    answer *= a;
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: Only there are much smarter (faster) ways to do it.

Comment: Note that this runs in O(N). A good pow implementation could run in O(logN)

Comment: This is very inefficient. And it doesn't compile. I think that OP imagined that `a` was a floating point value.

Comment: @luiscubal I think pow should be a lot better than `O(log N)`!!

Comment: @all haters (joking) -- I edited it to compile in a non c99 environment.  I hear you that it isn't efficient. :)

Comment: @David Heffernan - Just curious, could you provide an example(link if the explanation is too long) of pow algorithm better than O(logN)? A quick look at Wikipedia doesn't seem to suggest anything better than that...

Comment: @David: It *can* be O(1), but the tradeoff is that it consumes a *LOT* of space.

Comment: @luiscubal You can use the expression given by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Comment: @Chris Are you really still wanting to use default types for `a` and `b`?

Comment: @David Heffernan - But now the problem is twofold: implementing efficient e^x AND efficient ln(x)...

Comment: @luiscubal Use the hardware for those, make it somebody else's problem

Comment: @David Heffernan -- ah, good point!  This is what I get for working in Python/C/Java/Obj C/Scheme...too many different ways to define parameters.  I'll put in the ints...

Comment: Knuth volume 2, section 4.6.3 gives a tremendous exposition on the evaluation of powers