# Is using a math class method in a loop condition slow?

Tags: c#, loops, methods, conditional-statements

if i have a for loop for example and and i want to use something like Math.round() to round the number but i only need to round the number one time(i.e the number doesn't change throughout the loop) is it better to store it into a variable and then use the variable to in the condition or does it not matter?

```
 for (int i = 0;i < Math.Round(x);i++)
   {
   //Some code  
   }
```

vs

```
 for (int i = 0,roundedX = Math.Round(X); i<roundedX;i++)
  {  
  //Some code 
  }
```

Comment: If you like sloppy coding, then I guess it doesn't matter. Otherwise, just use a variable.

Comment: Just define roundedX = Math.Round(X); before the loop

Comment: FYI I would create an set the variable before the loop just for readability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler will evaluate the termination condition on every loop iteration.

The compiler and the JITter *might* hoist some expression or part of an expression outside the loop if it deems it is invariant, meaning it doesn't change. This, however, is usually only done with simpler expressions.

If the `Math.Round(X)` expression could've been done without an actual method call then *perhaps* but in this particular case the rounding will happen on each loop iteration.

As such, if you're at last line defense for performance problems, you might consider moving this out and into a variable:

```
int goal = (int)Math.Round(X);
for (int i = 0; i < goal; i++)
    ...
```

As this will call the `Math.Round` method only once, you only get the performance hit once.

Note that if `X` changes **as part of the loop**, then obviously you want to keep your original code.

Comment: I say "Performance hit" but most likely this will do very little or nothing to your performance. Unless you're doing very small workloads inside the loop, and have a very high end value, I would probably not bother with this.

Comment: It could be worthwhile for some Math methods - particularly if they are quite slow (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447282/why-is-math-divrem-so-inefficient ).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest defining a variable

```
 var roundedX = Math.Round(X);
 for (int i = 0; i < roundedX; i++)
 {  
    //Some code 
 }
```

Comment: Possible *final flourish*: `var roundedX = (int) Math.Round(X);` to prevent cast at `i < roundedX`